# Definir valor padrão do input sem aparecer pro usuário

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível eu definir um **valor padrão que seria o numero 0 sem que esse 0 fique a mostra pro usuário**, esse valor é necessário pois eu estou pegando esses números digitados e processando no PHP, eu armazeno em uma variável, e multiplico os valores, quando eu deixo um desses inputs vazios o PHP exibe um erro que diz que o valor não é um número preciso que esse numero 0 fique oculto para o usuario e funcione por baixo dos panos

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <input type="number" value="0">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cria um atributo para isso: `<input type="number" default-value="0">` mas lembre-se nada no hmtl fica mesmo sem acesso para o usuário, basta ver o código da página

Comment: Agora deu erro no meu PHP, o erro diz que é um valor non-numeric value encountered, um valor não númerico eu utilizei ele pra soma por isso ele mostra esse erro, a situação é simples mas tem algo por trás, SE eu não deixar o input vazio utilizando o numero 0 como value ele não gera erro de número, se eu utilizar esse atributo ele gera esse erro

Comment: Uma resposta usando JS te ajudaria?

Comment: sim, pode ser até no css se tiver

Comment: O que você quer dizer quando cita que esse valor não fique amostra ao usuário?

Comment: Sabe esse 0? que apareçe no lugar do input? o usuário vai ter que deletar ele manualmente, ou se ele não prestar atenção vai escrever por exemplo: "0100, 0200" por que o 0 ta ali, nada mais so quero que esse 0 fique  disponivel para o PHP não dar erro, gostaria (se existir) uma solução tipo a barra de pesquisa do google que ao clicar pode sobrescrever e por ai vai, ou você saberia uma solução para o PHP caso o input não conter nenhum numero recebido ele utilize o 0 na variável? o principal não é o html o problema tá em como o PHP vai processar...

Comment: @DanielElias, porque tu não deixa o valor sem nada e quando passa pro PHP ele elimina estes inputs com valor 0 ou simplesmente adiciona os 0 aos inputs que vem vazio?

Comment: Esse tipo de verificação deve ser feito no servidor, com PHP. Qualquer coisa que faça, seja com HTML ou JS, será gambiarra e terá efeitos colaterais. Basta você não definir o atributo `value` do campo e no PHP fazer a condição *se estiver vazio, atribua 0*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O placeholder foi utilizado para mostrar o número sem que o usuário possa interagir com ele:

```html
<input type="number" name="numero" placeholder="0" />
```

No PHP utilize a função [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) ela verifica se o valor esta vazio. Você pode verificar com um if para fazer o tratamento.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['numero'])) {
    // Trata caso o número que não foi informado
    $numero = 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Se não quer mostrar para o usuário use:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="vlalgumacoisa" value="0" />
```

No Php você pega o valor desse input tranquilamente, ele só não fica visível no formulário.

Comment: Você está equivocado. O AP quer um `<input type='number'>` que ao ser submetido vazio passe um valor default ao método HTTP responsável pelo envio dos dados. Os usuários estão explicando que não deve-se confiar com valores vindos do cliente e que esse tipo de validação deve ser feita no servidor